# One of the users in my org doesn't have Role and I am unable to edit his record

Tags: salesforce

I have the 2nd highest Role in my Org assigned to me and In a process of Data cleaning, I want to edit an "Account" record whose owner doesn't have a Role. Every time I am trying to edit it, error says **"You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary"**.
Is it a permissions issue or something to do in sharing settings? what kind of access should I get from the Admin/ Record owner in order to edit the record? (I have Edit access to all the objects in the Org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a Public Read Only or Private sharing model, as it sounds like is the case, your position near the top of the role hierarchy is irrelevant to your access to this record because you have no *relative position* to the Account's owner.

You'd have access roll up to you if you were above that user in the role hierarchy. But you're not - they aren't in the role hierarchy at all.

You could be granted Modify All Data or Modify All permission on the Account object, but it's unlikely your org will wish to do that. It's too broad a grant of power. The easiest solution is for the record owner to manually share the record to you with write permission. Alternately, a superuser in your org (like a System Administrator or some other designated person who has Modify All permission) can share the record to you or make you the owner outright.

Some orgs also choose to do data cleaning processes using Data Loader and an integration user that possesses elevated privileges to avoid this type of issue.